# How to convert Base64(postgres migrated byte[] to base64) to byte[] in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have converted byte[] to base64 in edb(postgres) using `(encode( bytedata::bytea, 'base64'))` and stored the base64 value in `clob` column. On java when I try to convert the base64 to byte[] I'm getting this error

> Last unit does not have enough valid bits

Any help welcome.

Comment: Why aren't you just storing the bytes in a blob column? There is no point whatsoever to base64-ing this.

Comment: Have to support storing byte[] in both edb and oracle. on oracle we are facing some issues. so we concluded to use clob datatype for storing byte[].

Comment: in edb, as a BLOB. In oracle... as a BLOB.

Comment: According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html clob is unsupported feature in postgresql.